# AJAX virtual pageviews not registered in Analytics (Global Site Tag and Barba.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-analytics, pageviews

I'm working on fixing the bounce rate of a website built using Barba.js for AJAX navigation. I've read multiple articles including Analytics' documentation regarding virtual pageviews and SPA's and cannot figure out why my pageviews are not registering.

When I access a page using the address bar or refreshing it, I pop up in Analytics live view, but not when navigating to another page using internal links (with Barba handling the page load).

Here's what I'm using to get the page path and send my pageview:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // other stuff  
  init_on_each_new_page();
});

function init_on_each_new_page() {
  // other stuff
  init_analytics();
}

function init_analytics() {
  // Grab the page URL, split at ".com"
  var $full_path = $(location).attr("href");
  var $path_split = $full_path.split(".com");
  var $ga_page_path;

  /* If there's something after .com and it's not just a slash, 
  make that the path sent to Analytics */
  if ($path_split[1] && $path_split[1] != "/") {
    var $path = $path_split[1];
    var $last_char = $path[$path.length - 1];
    if ($last_char == "/") {
      $ga_page_path = $path_split[1].slice(0, -1);
    } else {
      $ga_page_path = $path_split[1];
    }
  }
  /* If there's nothing after .com, we're on the homepage so the 
  path visited for Analytics is "/" */
  else {
    $ga_page_path = "/";
  }

  // Set GA page
  ga('set', 'page', $ga_page_path);
  // Send pageview
  ga('send', {
    'hitType': 'pageview',
    'hitCallback': function() {
      console.log('--> hit sent <--');
    }
  });
}
```

I added the hitCallback [like documented here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#hitCallback) to try and get a confirmation that the pageview was sent but nothing ever shows up in the console.

I can confirm that GA is correctly set up since "hard" pageviews are showing up.

I have seen a couple of threads regarding virtual pageviews on AJAX pages but all with previous versions of Analytics. I haven't found anything working with the new Global Site Tag. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include a path for your pageview, like so:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', location.pathname);
```

See: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages

Comment: The path is actually defined as $ga_page_path in the ga('set', 'page', $ga_page_path); action. I don't know it that was the right way of defining it but I tried to do it in the send and it didn't work either.

Comment: What is the conversion of this with gtag?

Answer (score 0):

It would have been obvious to some if I had posted my tracking code first but I figured out my mistake: I was using **ga** functions but with a **gtag** tracking code. I never thought twice about it because the tracking code was inserted a while before I started fixed the virtual page views and all my googling was bringing me to Analytics.js documentation.

See [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/migration) for migrating from Analytics.js to gtag.js and [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/single-page-applications) specifically for single page application tracking with gtag.js.